# get the intersected classes in SPARQL query using RDFLib

Tags: python, sparql, rdf, owl, rdflib

I have a class `ABC` that is a `subClassOf` the class `XYZ` and defined as intersections of classes `A`, `B`, `C` as:

```
<Class rdf:about="&clink;ABC">
    <equivalentClass>
        <Class>
            <intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                <Restriction>
                    <onProperty rdf:resource="&clink;affects"/>
                    <someValuesFrom rdf:resource="&clink;A"/>
                </Restriction>
                <Restriction>
                    <onProperty rdf:resource="&clink;hasMarker"/>
                    <someValuesFrom rdf:resource="&clink;B"/>
                </Restriction>
                <Restriction>
                    <onProperty rdf:resource="&clink;hasPathologicalProcess"/>
                    <someValuesFrom rdf:resource="&clink;C"/>
                </Restriction>
            </intersectionOf>
        </Class>
    </equivalentClass>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&clink;XYZ"/>
</Class>
```

How I can get access to the classes `A`, `B` and `C` through the class `XYZ` using SPARQL query in RDFLib?

The following query returns a blank node `rdflib.term.BNode('_L')` and I don't know how to handle the BNodes.

```
PREFIX rdf: h<ttp://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT ?subclass
WHERE {<XYZ> <rdf:subClassOf> <subclass>}
```

I need a query that receive the `XYZ` and returns this:

```
A
B
C
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `XYZ` is neither a `subClassOf` `A`, `B`, `C` nor a `subClassOf` their intersection `A and B and C` (I am using [manchester syntaax (see here)](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-manchester-syntax/)).

In your snippet, you define `XYZ` to be `equivalentTo` (which implies being a `subClassOf` as well) of the intersection of three [anynomous (see here)](https://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/P4AnonymousClasses) classes; which are `(affects some A) and (hasMaker some B) and (hasPathologicalProcess some C)`. This intersection is not equivalent to `A and B and C` (`some` in Manchester syntax stands for `someValuesFrom`).

To understand what `someValuesFrom` restriction means, see the [documentation (see here)](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl-ref/#someValuesFrom-def) of OWL:

> The value constraint `owl:someValuesFrom` is a built-in OWL property that
>   links a restriction class to a class description or a data range. A
>   restriction containing an `owl:someValuesFrom` constraint describes a
>   class of all individuals for which at least one value of the property
>   concerned is an instance of the class description or a data value in
>   the data range. In other words, it defines a class of individuals x
>   for which there is at least one `y` (either an instance of the class
>   description or value of the data range) such that the pair `(x,y)` is an
>   instance of `P`. This does not exclude that there are other instances
>   `(x,y')` of `P` for which `y'` does not belong to the class description or
>   data range.

**EDIT2:**

Now that you should have understood what `owl:someValuesFrom` means, and as @AKSW suggests, here is a straightforward SPARQL query. However, you cannot retrieve `A`, `B`, and `C` simply using `rdfs:subClassOf`! You should first retrieve the restriction, then access the property and the class it is defined on, as follows:

```
prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

select ?eqclass ?restriction ?onProp  ?someValuesFrom where {

  {?eqclass owl:equivalentClass/owl:intersectionOf _:b. _:b rdf:first ?restriction}
  # First anonymous class (restriction) in the collection
  UNION { ?eqclass owl:equivalentClass/owl:intersectionOf/(rdf:rest+/rdf:first+)*  ?restriction.} 
  # getting other anonymous classes (restriction) using property paths and rdf:first and rdf:rest used in RDF collections.       
  ?restriction  rdf:type owl:Restriction. 
  # individuals of type owl:Restriction
  ?restriction  owl:onProperty ?onProp. 
  # the property the restriciton is defined on which
  ?restriction  owl:someValuesFrom ?someValuesFrom.
  # the class of the owl:someValuesFrom property
}
```

**End of EDIT2**

**Other work around through modifying your data model.**

So first, your query should return the anonymous class `(affects some A) and (hasMaker some B) and (hasPathologicalProcess some C)` which is the intersection you define. However, as it is an anonymous class, a blank node `B_node` will be returned for it, rather than a concrete class. To return a concrete class, you should define this anonymous intersection as a class in your ontology for this intersection; for example, you can create the class `anyn_intersection`, as follows:

```
<owl:Class rdf:about="myPrefix#anyn_intersection">
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Class>
            <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                <owl:Restriction>
                    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="myPrefix#affects"/>
                    <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="myPrefix#A"/>
                </owl:Restriction>
                <owl:Restriction>
                    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="myPrefix#hasMaker"/>
                    <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="myPrefix#B"/>
                </owl:Restriction>
                <owl:Restriction>
                    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="myPrefix#hasPathologicalProcess"/>
                    <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="myPrefix#C"/>
                </owl:Restriction>
            </owl:intersectionOf>
        </owl:Class>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
</owl:Class>
```

Thus, your query will get this class `anyn_intersection` instead of the blank node.

Now If you want to get all of `(affects some A)`, `(hasMaker some B)`, and `(hasPathologicalProcess some C)` in the results, you should **first** *make sure that a reasoner is running* because this is an implicit knowledge and **second** you should *for each anonymous intersection class, define a concrete intersection class in a similar way to the `anyn_intersection`* above. For example, you can define `anyn_AffectsSomeA` for the anonymous restriction class: `affects some A` as follows:

```
<owl:Class rdf:about="myPrefix#anyn_AffectsSomeA">
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="myPrefix#affects"/>
            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="myPrefix#A"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
</owl:Class>
```

Then you have to define two similar classes `anyn_hasMakerSomeB` and `anyn_hasPathologicalProcessSomeC`. Finally, you define `anyn_intersection` as the intersection of `anyn_AffectsSomeA`, `anyn_hasMakerSomeB`, and `anyn_hasPathologicalProcessSomeC`.

**EDIT1:**

I am not aware if there is some specific feature in `rdfLib` that enables you to retrieve anonymous classes definitions. That might solve your problem without having to define it the way I suggest. Additionally, you should make sure a reasoner is running.

**End of EDIT1:**

Comment: The question was about using SPARQL to get the fillers of the object property restrictions. I don't see why somebody should introduce some artificial classes here. The answer should be more in the direction of showing the OWL mapping to RDF graphs, and then write the corresponding SPARQL query which is usually more complicated because of the fact that OWL constructs can consist of more than a single triple.

Comment: See my Edit2 of the answer.

Comment: The TO will probably not consider the query as "straightforward", but that's fine :D

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer.